# How do I assign a prefab as a target to a CameraControl script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I am doing the "Tanks!" tutorial for Unity and the guide told me to delete the tank object, as it was a Prefab and would use spawnpoints instead. I followed the videos, but it is telling me the m_Targets of CameraControl have not been assigned, as it is hidden in the inspector and is not meant to be modified according to the videos. I have rewatched all of them and this is my last resort. I have attempted modifying all the other scripts but they are not working, no matter what I do. I attempted using the completed versions of the tank and everything that was completed but it did not work, even the Camera control script itself. How can I get it to set the targets to 2 and use the prefabs of the tanks for the camera's target?

CameraControl.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Complete
{
    public class CameraControl : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float m_DampTime = 0.2f;                 // Approximate time for the camera to refocus.
        public float m_ScreenEdgeBuffer = 4f;           // Space between the top/bottom most target and the screen edge.
        public float m_MinSize = 6.5f;      

    /*[HideInInspector] */ public Transform[] m_Targets; // All the targets the camera needs to encompass.


    private Camera m_Camera;                        // Used for referencing the camera.
    private float m_ZoomSpeed;                      // Reference speed for the smooth damping of the orthographic size.
    private Vector3 m_MoveVelocity;                 // Reference velocity for the smooth damping of the position.
    private Vector3 m_DesiredPosition;              // The position the camera is moving towards.


    private void Awake ()
    {
        m_Camera = GetComponentInChildren<Camera> ();
    }


    private void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        // Move the camera towards a desired position.
        Move ();

        // Change the size of the camera based.
        Zoom ();
    }


    private void Move ()
    {
        // Find the average position of the targets.
        FindAveragePosition ();

        // Smoothly transition to that position.
        transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, m_DesiredPosition, ref m_MoveVelocity, m_DampTime);
    }


    private void FindAveragePosition ()
    {
        Vector3 averagePos = new Vector3 ();
        int numTargets = 0;

        // Go through all the targets and add their positions together.
        for (int i = 0; i < m_Targets.Length; i++)
        {
            // If the target isn't active, go on to the next one.
            if (!m_Targets[i].gameObject.activeSelf)
                continue;

            // Add to the average and increment the number of targets in the average.
            averagePos += m_Targets[i].position;
            numTargets++;
        }

        // If there are targets divide the sum of the positions by the number of them to find the average.
        if (numTargets > 0)
            averagePos /= numTargets;

        // Keep the same y value.
        averagePos.y = transform.position.y;

        // The desired position is the average position;
        m_DesiredPosition = averagePos;
    }


    private void Zoom ()
    {
        // Find the required size based on the desired position and smoothly transition to that size.
        float requiredSize = FindRequiredSize();
        m_Camera.orthographicSize = Mathf.SmoothDamp (m_Camera.orthographicSize, requiredSize, ref m_ZoomSpeed, m_DampTime);
    }


    private float FindRequiredSize ()
    {
        // Find the position the camera rig is moving towards in its local space.
        Vector3 desiredLocalPos = transform.InverseTransformPoint(m_DesiredPosition);

        // Start the camera's size calculation at zero.
        float size = 0f;

        // Go through all the targets...
        for (int i = 0; i < m_Targets.Length; i++)
        {
            // ... and if they aren't active continue on to the next target.
            if (!m_Targets[i].gameObject.activeSelf)
                continue;

            // Otherwise, find the position of the target in the camera's local space.
            Vector3 targetLocalPos = transform.InverseTransformPoint(m_Targets[i].position);

            // Find the position of the target from the desired position of the camera's local space.
            Vector3 desiredPosToTarget = targetLocalPos - desiredLocalPos;

            // Choose the largest out of the current size and the distance of the tank 'up' or 'down' from the camera.
            size = Mathf.Max(size, Mathf.Abs(desiredPosToTarget.y));

            // Choose the largest out of the current size and the calculated size based on the tank being to the left or right of the camera.
            size = Mathf.Max(size, Mathf.Abs(desiredPosToTarget.x) / m_Camera.aspect);
        }

        // Add the edge buffer to the size.
        size += m_ScreenEdgeBuffer;

        // Make sure the camera's size isn't below the minimum.
        size = Mathf.Max (size, m_MinSize);

        return size;
    }


    public void SetStartPositionAndSize ()
    {
        // Find the desired position.
        FindAveragePosition ();

        // Set the camera's position to the desired position without damping.
        transform.position = m_DesiredPosition;

        // Find and set the required size of the camera.
        m_Camera.orthographicSize = FindRequiredSize ();
    }
}
```

}

Game Manager:

```
    using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

namespace Complete
{
    public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public int m_NumRoundsToWin = 5;            // The number of rounds a single player has to win to win the game.
        public float m_StartDelay = 3f;             // The delay between the start of RoundStarting and RoundPlaying phases.
        public float m_EndDelay = 3f;               // The delay between the end of RoundPlaying and RoundEnding phases.
        public CameraControl m_CameraControl;       // Reference to the CameraControl script for control during different phases.
        public Text m_MessageText;                  // Reference to the overlay Text to display winning text, etc.
        public GameObject m_TankPrefab;             // Reference to the prefab the players will control.
        public TankManager[] m_Tanks;               // A collection of managers for enabling and disabling different aspects of the tanks.

    private int m_RoundNumber;                  // Which round the game is currently on.
    private WaitForSeconds m_StartWait;         // Used to have a delay whilst the round starts.
    private WaitForSeconds m_EndWait;           // Used to have a delay whilst the round or game ends.
    private TankManager m_RoundWinner;          // Reference to the winner of the current round.  Used to make an announcement of who won.
    private TankManager m_GameWinner;           // Reference to the winner of the game.  Used to make an announcement of who won.


    private void Start()
    {
        // Create the delays so they only have to be made once.
        m_StartWait = new WaitForSeconds (m_StartDelay);
        m_EndWait = new WaitForSeconds (m_EndDelay);

        SpawnAllTanks();
        SetCameraTargets();

        // Once the tanks have been created and the camera is using them as targets, start the game.
        StartCoroutine (GameLoop ());
    }


    private void SpawnAllTanks()
    {
        // For all the tanks...
        for (int i = 0; i < m_Tanks.Length; i++)
        {
            // ... create them, set their player number and references needed for control.
            m_Tanks[i].m_Instance =
                Instantiate(m_TankPrefab, m_Tanks[i].m_SpawnPoint.position, m_Tanks[i].m_SpawnPoint.rotation) as GameObject;
            m_Tanks[i].m_PlayerNumber = i + 1;
            m_Tanks[i].Setup();
        }
    }


    private void SetCameraTargets()
    {
        // Create a collection of transforms the same size as the number of tanks.
        Transform[] targets = new Transform[m_Tanks.Length];

        // For each of these transforms...
        for (int i = 0; i < targets.Length; i++)
        {
            // ... set it to the appropriate tank transform.
            targets[i] = m_Tanks[i].m_Instance.transform;
        }

        // These are the targets the camera should follow.
        m_CameraControl.m_Targets = targets;
    }


    // This is called from start and will run each phase of the game one after another.
    private IEnumerator GameLoop ()
    {
        // Start off by running the 'RoundStarting' coroutine but don't return until it's finished.
        yield return StartCoroutine (RoundStarting ());

        // Once the 'RoundStarting' coroutine is finished, run the 'RoundPlaying' coroutine but don't return until it's finished.
        yield return StartCoroutine (RoundPlaying());

        // Once execution has returned here, run the 'RoundEnding' coroutine, again don't return until it's finished.
        yield return StartCoroutine (RoundEnding());

        // This code is not run until 'RoundEnding' has finished.  At which point, check if a game winner has been found.
        if (m_GameWinner != null)
        {
            // If there is a game winner, restart the level.
            SceneManager.LoadScene (0);
        }
        else
        {
            // If there isn't a winner yet, restart this coroutine so the loop continues.
            // Note that this coroutine doesn't yield.  This means that the current version of the GameLoop will end.
            StartCoroutine (GameLoop ());
        }
    }


    private IEnumerator RoundStarting ()
    {
        // As soon as the round starts reset the tanks and make sure they can't move.
        ResetAllTanks ();
        DisableTankControl ();

        // Snap the camera's zoom and position to something appropriate for the reset tanks.
        m_CameraControl.SetStartPositionAndSize ();

        // Increment the round number and display text showing the players what round it is.
        m_RoundNumber++;
        m_MessageText.text = "ROUND " + m_RoundNumber;

        // Wait for the specified length of time until yielding control back to the game loop.
        yield return m_StartWait;
    }


    private IEnumerator RoundPlaying ()
    {
        // As soon as the round begins playing let the players control the tanks.
        EnableTankControl ();

        // Clear the text from the screen.
        m_MessageText.text = string.Empty;

        // While there is not one tank left...
        while (!OneTankLeft())
        {
            // ... return on the next frame.
            yield return null;
        }
    }


    private IEnumerator RoundEnding ()
    {
        // Stop tanks from moving.
        DisableTankControl ();

        // Clear the winner from the previous round.
        m_RoundWinner = null;

        // See if there is a winner now the round is over.
        m_RoundWinner = GetRoundWinner ();

        // If there is a winner, increment their score.
        if (m_RoundWinner != null)
            m_RoundWinner.m_Wins++;

        // Now the winner's score has been incremented, see if someone has one the game.
        m_GameWinner = GetGameWinner ();

        // Get a message based on the scores and whether or not there is a game winner and display it.
        string message = EndMessage ();
        m_MessageText.text = message;

        // Wait for the specified length of time until yielding control back to the game loop.
        yield return m_EndWait;
    }


    // This is used to check if there is one or fewer tanks remaining and thus the round should end.
    private bool OneTankLeft()
    {
        // Start the count of tanks left at zero.
        int numTanksLeft = 0;

        // Go through all the tanks...
        for (int i = 0; i < m_Tanks.Length; i++)
        {
            // ... and if they are active, increment the counter.
            if (m_Tanks[i].m_Instance.activeSelf)
                numTanksLeft++;
        }

        // If there are one or fewer tanks remaining return true, otherwise return false.
        return numTanksLeft <= 1;
    }


    // This function is to find out if there is a winner of the round.
    // This function is called with the assumption that 1 or fewer tanks are currently active.
    private TankManager GetRoundWinner()
    {
        // Go through all the tanks...
        for (int i = 0; i < m_Tanks.Length; i++)
        {
            // ... and if one of them is active, it is the winner so return it.
            if (m_Tanks[i].m_Instance.activeSelf)
                return m_Tanks[i];
        }

        // If none of the tanks are active it is a draw so return null.
        return null;
    }


    // This function is to find out if there is a winner of the game.
    private TankManager GetGameWinner()
    {
        // Go through all the tanks...
        for (int i = 0; i < m_Tanks.Length; i++)
        {
            // ... and if one of them has enough rounds to win the game, return it.
            if (m_Tanks[i].m_Wins == m_NumRoundsToWin)
                return m_Tanks[i];
        }

        // If no tanks have enough rounds to win, return null.
        return null;
    }


    // Returns a string message to display at the end of each round.
    private string EndMessage()
    {
        // By default when a round ends there are no winners so the default end message is a draw.
        string message = "DRAW!";

        // If there is a winner then change the message to reflect that.
        if (m_RoundWinner != null)
            message = m_RoundWinner.m_ColoredPlayerText + " WINS THE ROUND!";

        // Add some line breaks after the initial message.
        message += "\n\n\n\n";

        // Go through all the tanks and add each of their scores to the message.
        for (int i = 0; i < m_Tanks.Length; i++)
        {
            message += m_Tanks[i].m_ColoredPlayerText + ": " + m_Tanks[i].m_Wins + " WINS\n";
        }

        // If there is a game winner, change the entire message to reflect that.
        if (m_GameWinner != null)
            message = m_GameWinner.m_ColoredPlayerText + " WINS THE GAME!";

        return message;
    }


    // This function is used to turn all the tanks back on and reset their positions and properties.
    private void ResetAllTanks()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_Tanks.Length; i++)
        {
            m_Tanks[i].Reset();
        }
    }


    private void EnableTankControl()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_Tanks.Length; i++)
        {
            m_Tanks[i].EnableControl();
        }
    }


    private void DisableTankControl()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_Tanks.Length; i++)
        {
            m_Tanks[i].DisableControl();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Tank Manager:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Complete
{
    [Serializable]
    public class TankManager
    {
        // This class is to manage various settings on a tank.
        // It works with the GameManager class to control how the tanks behave
        // and whether or not players have control of their tank in the 
        // different phases of the game.

    public Color m_PlayerColor;                             // This is the color this tank will be tinted.
    public Transform m_SpawnPoint;                          // The position and direction the tank will have when it spawns.
    [HideInInspector] public int m_PlayerNumber;            // This specifies which player this the manager for.
    [HideInInspector] public string m_ColoredPlayerText;    // A string that represents the player with their number colored to match their tank.
    [HideInInspector] public GameObject m_Instance;         // A reference to the instance of the tank when it is created.
    [HideInInspector] public int m_Wins;                    // The number of wins this player has so far.


    private TankMovement m_Movement;                        // Reference to tank's movement script, used to disable and enable control.
    private TankShooting m_Shooting;                        // Reference to tank's shooting script, used to disable and enable control.
    private GameObject m_CanvasGameObject;                  // Used to disable the world space UI during the Starting and Ending phases of each round.


    public void Setup ()
    {
        // Get references to the components.
        m_Movement = m_Instance.GetComponent<TankMovement> ();
        m_Shooting = m_Instance.GetComponent<TankShooting> ();
        m_CanvasGameObject = m_Instance.GetComponentInChildren<Canvas> ().gameObject;

        // Set the player numbers to be consistent across the scripts.
        m_Movement.m_PlayerNumber = m_PlayerNumber;
        m_Shooting.m_PlayerNumber = m_PlayerNumber;

        // Create a string using the correct color that says 'PLAYER 1' etc based on the tank's color and the player's number.
        m_ColoredPlayerText = "<color=#" + ColorUtility.ToHtmlStringRGB(m_PlayerColor) + ">PLAYER " + m_PlayerNumber + "</color>";

        // Get all of the renderers of the tank.
        MeshRenderer[] renderers = m_Instance.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer> ();

        // Go through all the renderers...
        for (int i = 0; i < renderers.Length; i++)
        {
            // ... set their material color to the color specific to this tank.
            renderers[i].material.color = m_PlayerColor;
        }
    }


    // Used during the phases of the game where the player shouldn't be able to control their tank.
    public void DisableControl ()
    {
        m_Movement.enabled = false;
        m_Shooting.enabled = false;

        m_CanvasGameObject.SetActive (false);
    }


    // Used during the phases of the game where the player should be able to control their tank.
    public void EnableControl ()
    {
        m_Movement.enabled = true;
        m_Shooting.enabled = true;

        m_CanvasGameObject.SetActive (true);
    }


    // Used at the start of each round to put the tank into it's default state.
    public void Reset ()
    {
        m_Instance.transform.position = m_SpawnPoint.position;
        m_Instance.transform.rotation = m_SpawnPoint.rotation;

        m_Instance.SetActive (false);
        m_Instance.SetActive (true);
    }
}
```

}

```
Configurations: 

GameManager: 
Camera Control = CameraRig (CameraControl)
Message Text = Text (Text)
Tank Prefab = Tank 
--Tanks--
Size = 2
```

All of the spawn points are set to the positions from the video guides.

Comment: In general be careful with phrases: "Prefab" is a kind of template GameObject that can be instantiated on runtime .. your field is rather for "References" to stuff already existing in the Scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, some of the "Tanks!" tutorial steps have dependencies on later parts in the tutorial. Particularly, step 6: Game Managers.

Since m_Targets is exposed as a public field, it can be set from other scripts. This is exactly what the GameManager script does when it calls:

```
    private void SetCameraTargets()
    {
        // Create a collection of transforms the same size as the number of tanks.
        Transform[] targets = new Transform[m_Tanks.Length];

        // For each of these transforms...
        for (int i = 0; i < targets.Length; i++)
        {
            // ... set it to the appropriate tank transform.
            targets[i] = m_Tanks[i].m_Instance.transform;
        }

        // These are the targets the camera should follow.
        m_CameraControl.m_Targets = targets;
    }
```

In other words, **don't worry about the tanks not being set as camera targets yet. That is configured in step 6 of the tutorial.**

Comment: I am on step 7 of the project, and it has been shown to be functional, but it is not working for me. Thank you for wanting to help.

Comment: Please share your configuration of your GameManager.cs script in the inspector. @MrNeedHelpMan

Comment: I have added it. If I turn off the Targets again, it tells me Object reference not set to an instance of an object, with an issue being on line 36 of TankManager

Comment: That's unrelated to your camera issue. That's probably because you haven't assigned the TankShooting script to your object. @MrNeedHelpMan